# Expression engine multi-lingaul site on one install

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, expressionengine

I am currently working with expression engine, and we are wanting to create a multilingual site, using just one instance of expressionengine, without having to pay for the multi-site license.

For this reason I have a couple of questions?

1. I know it is possible to set up the system so we can a domain structure of something similar too, domain.com/fr/, domain.com/es/, domain.com/nl, however we are also wanting to show the site through the country specific domains would it be possible to rewrite the .com/fr/ domain in just domain.fr? And if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I am reading this correctly, but it seems you want to rewrite a path on one domain to read as though it were another site? Imagine how many banks would have fallen if this was possible. domain.com/fr and domain.fr are two different domains.

You can install ee on one site and have your other domains mirror the main site. Then switch language based on domain. I dont think ee sees this as two sites either, but you'd have to ask them and mention your server setup specifically. I don't know how ee works if there is one engine core that is shared by many sites. But Code Igniter can handle that easily, which is what I do on my CI based sites for sub-domains, which are essentially different sites in themselves.